# Projecting two vectors to have constant element-wise euclidean distances

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let $x = (x_{0}, \ldots, x_{n})$ and $y = (y_{0}, \ldots, y_{n})$ be two vectors, and $d = (d_{0} = x_{0} - y_{0}, \ldots, d_{n} = x_{n} - y_{n})$ their element-wise euclidean distances.

My question is, that is it possible to construct (invertible) projections $p, q$ so that the element-wise euclidean distances for $p(x), q(y)$ would be all equal, i.e. $d_{0}=d_{1}=\dots=d_{n}$?

I quess making $x$ and $y$ orthogonal would give a good start?

Comment: What do you mean by 'their element-wise euclidean distances'? $\|x-y\|$ usually means the norm, which is a scalar.

Comment: Sorry, my question was badly placed. I have now updated it. Is it now easier to follow? Sorry for bad english

Comment: Are $x,y$ vectors of vextors?

Comment: I guess I can start with $x_i, y_i$ being scalars. Sorry for all the notation trouble. Updated the question again

Comment: What is an "invertible projections"? Unless the word "projection" is meant in some different sense than it tends to be in linear algebra, the only invertible projection is the identity map...

Answer (score 1):

If for invertible projection you mean just an ivertible linear map $p$ such that $p^2=p$ then the answer is yes. If $x$ and $y$ are 0 then the identity map works. Assume that $\| x\|\leq\|y\|\neq 0$. Take $p=Id$. Let $D$ be the line $\mathbb{R}(1,\ldots,1)$. Take $y'\in x+D$ such that $\|y'\|=\|y\|$. It is easy to construct an invertible projection $q$ such that $q(y)=y'$. Then $p(x)=x$ and $q(y)=y'\in x+D$ and so their difference lies in $D$.